# VSCode Java extension gives error "Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse."

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I have a java project using gradle as my build system. I am developing in VSCode using the Java extension by Redhat. I am developing on Ubuntu 20.04 with openjdk 11.

When I build the project from the command line using './gradlew assemble', I don't get any build error.

But when I open the project in vscode, I get the following problem in the problems view...

```
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse. Fix the build path then try building this project
```

and...

```
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

My build.gradle is as follows....

```
plugins {
  id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '2.4.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'

// Use maven repository
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.4.19.v20190610'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:9.4.19.v20190610'
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-util', version: '9.4.29.v20200521'

    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.16'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.0.16'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:2.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jdbi:jdbi3-core:3.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev155-1.25.0'

    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.12'

    implementation 'com.github.bhlangonijr:chesslib:1.2.3'

    // compile project('chesslib')
    //runtime files('../../chesslib/build/libs/chesslib-1.1.12.jar')
}

task runServer(type: JavaExec) {
    enableAssertions = true
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath 
    main = 'ChessServer'
} 

task runClient(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath 
    main = 'ChessClient'
    standardInput = System.in // without this, using Scanner on System.in won't work
}

task runCLITestApp(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath 
    main = 'CLITestApp'
    standardInput = System.in
}

// use cloudBuilder.py to invoke this jib task to build the container
// use cloudConfiguration.json to configure things like container version.
jib {
    if (project.hasProperty('googleCloudProjectName') && project.hasProperty('imageName')) {
        to {
          image = "gcr.io/$googleCloudProjectName/$imageName"
        }
        container {
            mainClass = 'ChessServer'
            ports = ['8080']
            creationTime = "USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
        }
    }
}

// make sure the required project properties are set for jib
task jibCheck {
    doLast {
        if (!project.hasProperty('googleCloudProjectName'))
            throw new GradleException("When invoking the jib task, make sure to pass the cli arg -PgoogleCloudProject=[myGoogleCloudProject]\nThis should be the name of the google cloud project which container registry you want to push to.");
        if (!project.hasProperty('imageName'))
            throw new GradleException("When invoking the jib task, make sure to pass the cli arg -PimageName=[imageName]");
    }
}
tasks.jib.dependsOn tasks.jibCheck

// src/main/jib is the default folder that jib looks for files to add to your container
// these files will be placed in the root / dir of the container
task moveFilesForJib(type: Copy) {
    from "releaseFiles"
    into "src/main/jib"
}
tasks.jib.dependsOn tasks.moveFilesForJib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run

```
./gradlew wrapper
```

Then in vscode run Java: Clean Workspace.

Comment: You may accept your answer to show question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `build.gradle`. After rebuilding the project, see if the error goes away.

```
compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
```

Comment: That did not make a difference. I suspect the issue has nothing to do with the build.gradle, and something to do with the vscode extension configuration.

Comment: @Scorb. Note that Java extension needs jdk11 or recent version to support. Open Command Palette and choose **Java：Clean Java Language Server Workspace**, does it help?

Comment: java.home is not set, and it has worked fine like this so far. I am using openjdk 11 on ubuntu 20.04. Java is by default added to the environment.

Comment: @Scorb Are there by any chance multiple JDKs on your machine?